# How do I write down "the set of all rational functions in one variable over $ \mathbb C$"?

Tags: notation, rational-functions

What is the best way to write down "the set of all rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$"?

This is what I have tried:

$$
\mathbb{C}(t) = \left\{ \frac{P(t)}{Q(t)} \Big| t \in \mathbb{C}, \; P(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_{i}t^n, \; Q(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{k \in \mathbb{N}}b_{j}t^n\Big| \right\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

In the notation of abstract algebra: $$\Bbb C(z)$$

Comment: That notation is indeed standard. If the OP has to define it before using it, the best definition is the English phrase in the question, not a restatement in formal logic.